# Why running pip install -U Flask results in cannot import name 'parse_rule' from 'werkzeug.routing' error?

Tags: flask, werkzeug

After running **pip install -U Flask**, is successfully installed Flask-2.3.2 and Werkzeug-2.3.4. After this came the cannot import name 'parse_rule' from 'werkzeug.routing' error.

When searching online, the only solution that worked was:

```
pip3 install Flask==2.1.2
pip3 install Werkzeug==2.1.2
```

So the question is how did Flask was able to advance to version 2.3.2, when it is not possible to run it past version 2.1.2?

Comment: please show your code and the full stack trace